# iis url rewrite works one old server but not on new

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have been using url rewrite on my server with iis7 Win server 2008 RC2 for several years and it works great. Now, I try to move the whole configuration to a new (virtual) server (same OS) but it just doesn't work. The purpose with the rewrite is to avoid port numbers in URL's (":"). Here is my web.config located in a subfolder /834 so that the user can enter mysite/834 instead of mysite:834.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="tp_redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern=".+(834)/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://teamplay.vps.mibosoft.se:{C:1}/{C:2}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As mentioned earlier, this config works great on my old server. Here is what I did on the new server:

1. Installed the url rewrite module (also tried re-installing).
2. Installed ARR (do I need this?).

Interesting is that if I change action type="Rewrite" into action type="Redirect", then it works but I need rewrite and not redirect. Wwwroot structure is identical on both servers.

This makes me crazy. Any ideas?

Comment: No hints? This was a silent forum...

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I compared the files %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config between the servers and saw that section "rewrite" below was missing and also the line proxy enabled="true".

```
        <validation />
        <rewrite>
            <globalRules>
                <clear />
            </globalRules>
            <allowedServerVariables>
            </allowedServerVariables>
            <outboundRules>
            </outboundRules>
            <rewriteMaps>
            </rewriteMaps>
        </rewrite>
        <diskCache>
            <compression>
                <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
                <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
            </compression>
        </diskCache>
        <proxy enabled="true" />
```

When I added these lines, it started working. Magic. I wonder why...

Comment: where within the file did you put this config?

Comment: i think it was the <proxy enabled="true" /> for me